# Shadows with CoreGraphics?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

What is the proper way to implement shadows with CoreGraphics? I've looked around but haven't been able to find a whole lot on it. Is there a simple method for adding a shadow to a view, or will I have to subclass and override the drawRect: method?

Comment: What kind of shadows? I'd think different shadows are implemented in different ways. Do you mean the "gradient" drop shadows seen under navigation bars, toolbars and table cells?

Comment: I don't know what type of shadows there are. I just want a simple grey shadow that appears below my view to give a 3D effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Quartz 2D Programing Guide: Shadows](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_shadows/dq_shadows.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH208-TPXREF101). Basically, you call `CGContextSetShadow(CGContextRef context, CGSize shadowSize, CGFloat blurValue)` and then do your drawing.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use CALayer shadows on any existing view, but the performance penalty is terrible. I don't recommend doing it, especially if you are supporting older devices.

```
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0);
view.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
view.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0;
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
```

Comment: For the code above to work you need to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`